# Archive submission failed: ITMS-4238 "Redundant binary upload"

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

When attempting to submit an app from Xcode 6 Organizer to iTunes Connect, I receive the following error:

> ERROR ITMS-4238 "Redundant binary upload. There already exists a binary upload with build version '1.0' for train '1.0'"

Application Loader also fails with the same error. How can I upload my app?

Answer (score 7):

If you have already uploaded a binary and have rejected it and wish to upload to the same version number:

Go to your plist file and change "CFBundleVersion" so if you're uploading version 1.2 change it to 1.2.1 but keep the "CFBundleShortVersionString" as 1.2 so you should have

CFBundleShortVersionString - 1.2
CFBundleVersion - 1.2.1

Archive and submit, then in iTunes Connect you will see all the builds you have submitted for the version 1.2

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to upload a binary with the same build version as the current uploaded build, version 1.0. New versions of apps need a new version number to distinguish them, such as 1.0.1 or 1.1.

Comment: Does it mean I have already uploaded a binary but didn't submit that for preview? (Status prepare for preview)

Answer (score 1):

Change the build number, and build again before archiving. This worked for me.